# Do Visual Studio 2008 macros have to be written in VB.Net?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

Probably a stupid question but, do Visual Studio 2008 macros have to be written in VB.Net? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, VB.NET is your only choice.

Comment: That's too bad.It hurts to read it and hurts even more to write it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unfortunately VS2008 macros can only be written in VB.NET.